# TinyMCE V6.7 not working with Coldfusion 2021

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to use TinyMCE V6.7 in Coldfusion 2021. I tried both the free SDK and the cloud version and both give the error "Failed to initialize the editor as the document is not in standards mode.
TinyMCE requires standards mode." .
I have tried every code sample I can find with the same result. I need help resolving this.

Here is the code I used:

--- Cloud Version:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea>Next, use our Get Started docs to setup Tiny!</textarea>
</body>
```

Next, use our Get Started docs to setup Tiny!

I also tried :

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

---SDK version:

```
    tinyMCE.init({ 
        // General options
        selector : "textarea#testone",
        width : 500,
        height: 200,
        theme : "advanced",
        skin : "o2k7",
        // Theme options            
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_path : false,
        theme_advanced_resizing : true
    });


<h1>TinyMCE Quick Start Guide</h1>

<form method="post">
<tinymce-editor>
  <textarea name="mytextarea" id="mytextarea">Hello, World!</textarea>
</tinymce-editor>
</form>
```

I was expecting the textbox with the control bar on top.

I got the textbox without any controls and the error message "Failed to initialize the editor as the document is not in standards mode. TinyMCE requires standards mode."

Comment: Do you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your file? According to this article that could be the issue if it is missing. https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-requires-standards-mode/

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. I have found where others have used this but nothing for the current version of ColdFusion and TinyMCE 6.7. It's almost like they are incompatible which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your code says ` selector : "textarea#testone"`, yet, there is no textarea with that id

Comment: ^^^ Exactly this. It's a JavaScript error, not a ColdFuison issue.

Comment: this is more a javascript question. have you seen that your init() code line is before the dom building, and you are not waiting for the load of the dom to initiate the plugin? what happens if you move the textarea more to the top (before the initialisation), so that the init-line comes after?

Comment: Untagging ColdFusion. As demonstrated _by the example code_, which is entirely mark-up and JS, this is nothing to do with CF or CFML.

Comment: I googled "Failed to initialize the editor as the document is not in standards mode. TinyMCE requires standards mode." and the first match - from the TinyMCE docs - explained what's going on here. Or at least it seems to. Did you google the error message and have a read / act on the advice given?

Comment: I found a possible problem causing this issue. ColdFusion pre-compiles all code when cache is turned on. It also places a comment (<!--- http://servername/index.cfm---> ) on the first line of the page when cache is on. !DOCTYPE...> no longer works since it is now on the second line. This causes the !DOCTYPE to NOT be in Standard mode. I'm still trying to figure out the fix for this.